# How could I easily pack a directory to an ext4 loop partition image?

Tags: linux, ext4

I would like to pack the content of a directory into an ext4 partition image easily, **without** mounting a loop device.

Background: I am building a version of Android which will mount system partitions as a loop device for ARM. Though I can create those partition images by hand using loop devices, it is very troublesome. I want to use an `sh` script to automatically do the work, and *without* needing to loop mount the `dd`-created image and use `cp -rp`. The best is to directly pack the files into an image file.

Question: Is there any simple command-line tools *without* needing loop mount and root permission that can pack files into an `ext4` partition image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Android build system there is a host binary `make_ext4fs`. You can create ext4 images by this way:

```
make_ext4fs [ -l <len> ] [ -j <journal size> ] [ -b <block_size> ]
    [ -g <blocks per group> ] [ -i <inodes> ] [ -I <inode size> ]
    [ -L <label> ] [ -f ] [ -a <android mountpoint> ]
    [ -z | -s ] [ -J ]
    <filename> [<directory>]
```

Comment: Hello, will this work for x86 devices?

Comment: Can you define journal size block size, inodes, inode size, label android mountpoint  and -z -s -j ?